# swift: how to Open Safari App (not a link therein)

Tags: ios, swift, safari

I want to move users to safari. but do not want to open each time a new tab. is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can implement webview also, open a link in app

Comment: i need an origianal and full safari..

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav is right. You should implement webview.

Comment: solved: x-web-search://

Answer (score 2):

solved

```
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "x-web-search://")!)
```